# Android studio not open

Tags: flutter, android-studio, intellij-plugin, flutter-doctor

[image: 1]

Initially, 'unable to find bundled java version' tried to resolve the error and corrected it by replacing 'jdk' with 'jre'. However, Android studios have not opened since then.

When I reinstalled the Android studio, it worked normally, but it did not open after changing it to 'jre' again with the same error.

What's the problem with the program not opening at all? plz..
What should I do..?

I tried reinstalling it, but it failed.
and
'https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues?hl=ko#studio-config-directories'

I tried to follow the solution that came out of this,
It was difficult to find the Android studio version and followed the path of the new and old versions, but there was no corresponding file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olht2.png)
→ My path : ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2022.1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJWDj.png)
At the end of the old route, there is no Android 'a'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should duplicate jbr and rename the copies folder ‘jre’.
You need to have the two folders 'jbr' and 'jre' with the same content not renaming the original one.